# iterate over json object of arrays from ionic 2 post request

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, ionic2

I guess I'm stuck on stupid. I've been at this for the last few hours and can't seen to figure it out. Admittedly, I am new to ng/ionic2.
I am trying to loop through the response from my post request. I am getting a valid(validated online) big, fat JSON object from my own web api. It looks like this:

```
 `"details": [{
            "item_ID": "4",
            "item_attribute_ID": "JiggyJamband_1_642",
            "item_color_bool": "false",
            "item_name": "Test Item 4",
            "item_price": "18.95",
            "item_desc": "4 This is a test of the ajax input",
            "item_gender": "Girls"
        },
    { ... },
    "attributes": {
            "JiggyJamband_1_642": [{
                "color": "no-color",
                "Xs": "80",
                "Sm": "0",
                "Med": "0",
                "Lrg": "0",
                "Xl": "0",
                "Xxl": "10"
            }],
            "JiggyJamband_5_5664": [{
                "color": "no-color",
                "Xs": "0",
                "Sm": "0",
                "Med": "0",
                "Lrg": "0",
                "Xl": "0",
                "Xxl": "50"
            }],
    { ... }`
```

I am able to access individual "details" and "attributes" like this:

```
this.itemsDataService.getRemoteData(urlCode)
     .subscribe(response => {
        this.itemsJson = response;
          this.dObj = this.boothItemsJson.details;
          //this.aObj = this.boothItemsJson.attributes;
          this.aObj = response["attributes"]["JiggyJamband_1_642"];
});
```

My provider looks like this:

```
getRemoteData(urlCode): any {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/process-fe-app/_itemJson.php', JSON.stringify(urlCode))
              .map(res => res.json());   }
```

**My question:** items in details is dynamic and has an item-attribute_ID that is related to at least 1 entry in attributes. Entrys for attributes are dynamic as well - each item can have multiple attributes. The array keys of the individual attributes are the static (sizes and colors) and either have values or they don't. I need to be able to loop over the attributes object (aObj) of arrays and the arrays inside them. I do not need the ngFor or ngIf statements as this data won't be directly displayed per se. The json data is returned just fine but I just need to be able to access it call methods on the based on the data (like putting into storage with the attribute ID as the key "JiggyJamband: color: no-color, xs:50, s:100... etc"

**What I've tried:** this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kHJgw6Li_4, and googling ever iteration of the wording for this problem I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this sample iteration will help you get your head around it.

```
this.itemsDataService.getRemoteData(urlCode)
     .subscribe(response => {
          for(var k in response){
              for(var k2 in response[k]){
                   console.log([k,k2,response[k][k2]]);
              }
          } 
});
```

Comment: @ kpie - man thanks for the crisp, clean answer. I was looking right past the obvious. D'oh!

Comment: Everything you know how to do is hardest the first time you do it : )